# iphone using 2 tableview

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I 'm a iphone programming newbie. I m trying to implement an app with multi-level tableviews.

The idea is if someone selects something on the first screen say then a new view opens(tableview)

```
  car make> list of models   
  Honda > Acura, S2000,accord ...
```

My challenge is to show the list of models in a new tableview & secondly change the size of hte list depending on the car selected.

I have programmed so that when i select 'Honda' a new tableview opens.
How do i populate data for the second table??

Any suggestions on how to proceed?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer documentation [Navigating a Data Hierarchy With Table Views](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html) will give you some hints how to do that.

Your second table needs (as the first one) an data source delegate. Before pushing the second table view controller set a "car-model" property to "Honda" so that your second table data source delegate can, for example, get the data from a NSDictionary with all your "car models" as keys and your list as array. Use that array as tableview data source.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the data for the second table exactly the same way as you populated the first.

It sounds as though you might not be using a UINavigationController. If not, you should be.

Read the whole of the iPhone Programming Guide.